# How to extract the first occurrence of 7 to 10 digits of a string in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

From the following strings:

```
123456789 asd @ . 1234567 asdhhch 1234567890
as@ 12345 asdcc 1234567 1234567890
.1 .123456 .12345678 .123456789
asd 11111 1234567800
```

How can I extract the first ocurrence of 7 to 10 digits in bigquery - SQL Standard?

```
123456789
1234567
12345678
1234567800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select txt, regexp_extract(txt, r'\d{7,10}')
from table
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)